# IE9 is confused whether to use standards, or Microsoft Proprietary opacity

Tags: jquery, css, html-table, internet-explorer-9, opacity

Internet Explorer 9 now supports both the opacity rule and the filter rule.

This causes a problem. See [Example](http://jsfiddle.net/TRFDL/)

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>To standard or not to standard</title>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.js"></script>
  <style type="text/css">
    form, table { opacity: 0; filter: alpha(opacity=0); }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <form action="javascript:">
    Now you see me...
    <table><tr><td>Now you don't!</td></tr></table>
  </form>
  <script>
    $('form, table').animate({
        opacity: 1
    });
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

If you view this in IE9, the table will disappear as soon as the animation completes
(beware, if you reload, it may switch to IE7 document standards, go back to IE9 using the F12 tools)

The problem is caused by the inline CSS using only the standard `opacity` rule, and not the `filter` rule.

Notice that the parent form has no problem.

In the real world, the table opacity is animated only after an async operation is complete. That is why I cannot put the opacity on the table only.

How would you suggest I overcome this? I was thinking maybe an IE conditional version code in the CSS, or perhaps some additional JavaScript. I could also stop using a table which *seems* to fix it also, but I wanted to know what you would recommend.

**Edit:** In case you wonder why I am using a table.

I am using the following layout.

```
label A:      [input    ]
label Second: [input    ] [button]
```

The advantages I find here are

- The first column automatically sets its width to the widest label.
- The row height is automatically determined by the largest element, in this case that would be the button.
- The label is vertically aligned middle which is more pleasing when aligning to the input.

**Alternative A:** Div float left align right. With a visibility hidden button on the first row in order to get blank space of exact width for consistent alignment.

**Alternative B:** Floating divs with hard-coded width for the labels and a fixed line height for the vertical align and row height desired.

Answer (score 6):

I'd stop using a table.

Unless you're specifically showing tabular data. In which case, stick the filter rule into a conditional comment targeting IE8 and below

Comment: I listed why I am using a table. Would you recommend alternative A or B?

Comment: I normally use option B personally, but without divs, just labels and inputs. Labels and inputs both floated left, labels with clear:left

Comment: I like the simplicity of that, though I hate to hard-code the dimensions.

Comment: I know what you mean, but I prefer to adjust the CSS if necessary in favour of simple HTML :)

Answer (score 2):

It's a little unclear what end-result or effect you're trying to achieve.  Why are you using a `form` with the `action="javascript;"` when jQuery could handle it nicely?

---

**1)**  Stop using `tables` for layout.  If it fixes the other issues, then great, but that's only a side benefit.

---

**2a)**  You're already using jQuery, so you could initially set opacity with it on DOM ready.  The benefit is that jQuery then handles any cross browser issues with opacity.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('form, table').css('opacity', 0);
});
```

---

**2b)**  Alternatively, you can simply use jQuery's [`.hide()`](http://api.jquery.com/hide/) and [`.show()`](http://api.jquery.com/show/), which, when used with `duration`, animates the opacity.

On DOM ready, it's hidden...

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('form, table').hide('fast');
});
```

and inside whatever function to show it...

```
$('form, table').show('slow');
```

---

**2c)**  Or better yet, don't use opacity to hide it initially...

```
form, table { display: none; }
```

and inside whatever function to show it...

```
$('form, table').show('slow');
```

---

**EDIT:**

As per comments:

```
<form action="#" ...
```

Does not require a `return false` if you use `preventDefault` in the submit handler...

```
$('form').submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();  // this is first line.
    //  the rest of your submit function
});
```

Comment: I just use `action=javascript:` because action is a required field according to standards. I have to put something there. I am using a `submit` event so it does not matter unless there is a JavaScript failure, which is unlikely in my case. **1** I listed why I am using the table, and the two alternatives I can think of. Would you recommend one of those alternatives? **2a** I am slightly against that, because if the page does not load right away, the ready event will not fire right away, and the form and table would be visible for a short time before disappearing and animating back.

Comment: **2c** Sounds like a good idea, though I would use visibility hidden on the table instead of display none, and add to the javascript to keep the outer form from resizing (it has a visible border and in reality is animated in *before* the table animation starts). On an aside note, if I wasn't going to use CSS visibility, I would use `.animate({opacity:'show'})` which allows me to control which properties are animated.

Comment: jQuery uses the filter property to set opacity. Not sure if it does this with IE9, but certainly with older versions.

Comment: @danwellman, Apparently it does **not** use filter with IE9 and that is where the problem arises. But only because the CSS is using filter and this quirk with the child table. The outer form does not have the problem.

Comment: @GeorgeBailey, since you're using a submit handler, simply use `action="#"` to remain HTML compliant.  Less confusion.

Comment: @Sparky672, Though it does require me to add a `return false`. :(

Comment: @GeorgeBailey, no, it does not.  You would simply add a `preventDefault()` to the submit handler.  See my edit.

Comment: That is nice to know! However, I think lazy old me is going to stick with the original solution that does not require one of `e.preventDefault()` or `return false`.

Comment: @GeorgeBailey, You'll never be sorry by moving away from hacky code, old habits and inline JavaScript... unleash the power of jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

I am fine with leaving tables (even after the arguments they bring), so I will favor minimal modifications.

> In the real world, the table opacity is animated only after an async operation is complete.

The solution I ended up using was replacing
JavaScript `$('form').animate({opacity: 1})`
with `$('form').animate({opacity: 1}); $('table').css({opacity: 0})`

And replacing
CSS `form, table { opacity 0; filter: alpha(opacity=0); }`
with `form { opacity 0; filter: alpha(opacity=0); }`.

Thank you everyone for your input. I often learn something new when posting questions here.